ORA-01017 Error in Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code
I am unable to connect to the database due to an ORA-01017 error. I have two types of accounts: a personal account and a team account, which are formatted as follows:

Personal account = user_name
Team account = user_name[team_name]

I can easily connect using my personal account, but I can't seem to connect with the team account.
Full error message:

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-01017/. Network config file
location: /Users/.../Oracle/network/admin

What's puzzling is that I can connect using user_name[team_name] in other tools like DBeaver and PL/SQL Developer without any issues.
Using "user_name[team_name]", 'user_name[team_name]', and user_name\[team_name\] hasn't resolved the issue.
Version: Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code (SQL and PLSQL) = v23.4.1

Please provide the complete, exact error message, not just an error number. There is a description of the error provided in that message. We shouldn't have to Google the error number to find out what it means when you have that information already available right in front of you on your screen. You're asking US to help YOU, and you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so by giving us the details you have.

@KenWhite, thank you for the valid remark.

The square brackets indicate that you're trying to connect as a proxy user.
The Oracle Developer Tools for VSCode have some extra steps you need to take for this type of authentication:

check the Show more options checkbox and provide the proxy username
and password

In your example, the "proxy username" is user_name; the password is that user's password.
For the "username", you'll enter team_name; the password for that should be blank.
(see also here for similar directions, and this screenshot:)


I currently can't react to your answer, but it was very helpful. Thank you very much!
